# How to create 100 unique Ubuntu VM's with virtualbox the fast way?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, ubuntu-server

I want to create 100 Ubuntu VM's with virtualbox via commandline.
Each Ubuntu VM should have its own unique /etc/machine-id value
and unique mac address of the network adapter.
There is a file with 100 hostnames (password doesn't matter) and every new Ubuntu VM should get a name assigned from this list.

If i clone 100 times an existing VM then all the new cloned VM's hav the same /etc/machine-id + username + mac address and i have to manually change everything to a new unique one - i dont like that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Clone, and change the IDs in the `.vbox` file using `sed`.  Example,

```
sed -i -e "s/\(MACAddress=\"......\)....../\1$(openssl rand -hex 3)/" vm.vbox
sed -i -e "s/\(Machine uuid=\".........-....-....-....-\)............/\1$(openssl rand -hex 6)/" vm.vbox
```

You can tidy up the `sed` and make more complete UUID's, but this is the basic principle.  Script it for each `.vbox`.

Comment: .vbox file editing the macs and UUID's does not work: I've cloned via the GUI an Ubuntu VM. I've compared the original .vbox file and the cloned .vbox file.
Machine uuid, HardDisk uuid, MACAddress values are already different in .vbox files but **cat /etc/machine-id**  on each Ubuntu VM shows **identical values**.

So changing UUID's in .vbox file doesnt effect the /etc/machine-id

Comment: Mount the `vmdk` and change it there too.

Comment: Sorry i don't get it. The clone.vdi is already mounted in the VM. And the file itself is on a windows partition and i don't think i can edit this clone.vdi file with an editor (at least in windows it is not possible. clone.vdi has a file size of 3gb ). Sorry, im a total noob and im totally confused. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Or do you man i have to change the UUID's in the .vbox file and then .vdi file8 (vmdk) needs to be updated (rewritten) and then Virtualbox needs to remount this updated .vdi file?

Comment: /etc/machine-id is set at the installation of ubuntu so i think i have to use dbus-uuidgen for each virtual machine to have different uuids on each vm. i can write a script which opens an openssh connection to each vm, use dbus-uuidgen to generate a unique uuid for /etc/machine-id - what do you think?

Comment: Mount the `vdi` file in the host, there's plenty of existing questions about that, e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327728/mounting-vmdk-disk-image.  Let's say it is mounted at `/mnt/vdi`, then edit `/mnt/vdi/etc/machine-id` and unmount.  You should be able to script that.  Or alternatively use `cloudinit` which should set that sort of stuff on first boot.

Comment: My host system is windows 10 and the .vdi has dynamic size option (not fixed size). I've used 2 tools like ImDisk to mount .vdi but it fails due to the dynamic size option which i have had chosen when i have setup the vm at the beginning....

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vagrant to provision many machines at once by creating a “Multi-Machine” environment: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/multi-machine

Vagrant uses a config file that defines the environment and individual machines. It’s trivial to add additional machines:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo Hello"

  config.vm.define "web" do |web|
    web.vm.box = "apache"
  end

  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.box = "mysql"
  end
end
```

With some clever text processing in vscode, it’s trivial to turn your list into a config section.